# how to convert string to number

Tags: java

I have a code :

```
String sum = mDBHelper.SumIn(tglawal, tglakhir);
jmlh.setText("Amount of your income : Rp " + sum);
```

This outputs:

```
200000
```

Now I want to put the value with format `200.000`.

Comment: question and description contradicts.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int i = 1412214;
String s = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(i);
```

An another easy example:

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1412214));
```

Output: `1,412,214`

PS: RP = Riot Points?? :O

Answer (score 1):

You can use **String.format** to achive that.

For format specification you can have a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: he would have found that using google.... it is a waste that normal people have to do that...

Comment: ITroubs, I don't know what is your point.... he asked a question and I point him in the right direction.. I think its better then simply rejection and saying... use google

Comment: I didn't know the answer but it took me less time to find what he wanted in google than it took to write down the question and wait for the answers. not using google for such trivial questions is pure lazynes and a waste of time of other people who read these questions and answer them.

Comment: searching for `number output format java` and cklicking on the first link took 5 seconds and led me to the almost exact same page as you posted.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
double doubleValue;

try
{
    Number inValue = format.parse("200.000");
    doubleValue = inValue.doubleValue();
} catch (ParseException e)
{
    doubleValue = 0.0;
}
```

you can parse int, long ... change method in this line

```
doubleValue = inValue.doubleValue();
```

for example:

```
int number = inValue.intValue();
```

I hope, this help you.